# SyntaxError: invalid syntax when trying migrate

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=256, unique=True)
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
form appTwo.moldels import User
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'appTwo/index.html')


def users(request):
    user_list = User.object.order_by('first_name')
    user_dict = {'users':user_list}
    return render(request, 'appTwo/users.html', context=user_dict)
```

[protwo/urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra3oN.png)

**appTwo/urls.py**

```py
from django.conf.urls import path
from appTwo import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.users, name='users'),
]
```

I've tried migrating but it causes a syntax error. The stack trace is included below:

```
File "/home/hamid/Desktop/my_django_stuff/project_two/proTwo/proTwo/urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from appTwo import views
  File "/home/hamid/Desktop/my_django_stuff/project_two/proTwo/appTwo/views.py", line 2
    form appTwo.moldels import User
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
(myDjango) hamid@hamid-PC:~/Desktop/my_django_stuff/project_two/proTwo$
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please add some more information to the body of your question about what you are trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled models:

```
form appTwo.moldels import User
```

to

```
form appTwo.models import User
```

Comment: i changed but give same erorrFile "/home/hamid/Desktop/my_django_stuff/project_two/proTwo/proTwo/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from appTwo import views
  File "/home/hamid/Desktop/my_django_stuff/project_two/proTwo/appTwo/views.py", line 2
    form appTwo.models import User

Answer (score 2):

Other than the typo in "moldels" pointed out by FBSO, there is also another in the same line in "form", it should be "from":

```
from appTwo.models import User
```